# i am not able to install windows7 after installing ubuntu on dell latitude d430

Tags: system

First I had install Ubuntu.Now I want to remove ubuntu and  install windows7 by usb but i am not able to install windows 7. Please suggest me way to install windows 7

Answer (score 0):

U just have to put your DVD or USB device.
Then U have to select Boot to UEFI mode from Boot device menu. U will find it in your boot setup options.
Then using Shift+F10 switch to CMD prompt.
There u will type "diskpart".
After that identify the drive to reformat using "list disk" command.
Then select the drive, reformat it using following commands,
     select disk 
     clean
     convert gpt
     exit
After that close the command prompt.
Continue the Windows Setup installation. When choosing installation type choose CUSTOM.
The drive will appear as a single area of un-allocated space. Select the unallocated space and click Next. Windows begins the installation.
During reformat step, choose the drive in which u have installed Ubuntu. After that it removed from your PC. If you want then u can dual boot your PC with W 7 and Ubuntu.